# when i copy my html file in jsp and css file then my page design change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsp, tomcat

I am working on a project.Initially I worked in dreamweaver and created some html files and css for project interface. when i run `index.html` , in case of single folder contain all html files and css it run well no change in design and every div in its proper place and everything is well but now i am using neatbean and tomcat to run my project in java so for this purpose when i copy my html file code in jsp along with css and after deployment when i run index.jsp its design got changed and everything is mixed with each other for example menu and header mixed with each other and my page design corrupted. some one tell me how i can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because you open a new file for the project, and copy the code of the html,css directly, if you have open a new project in netbeans for example the default folder of that project is in C:\Users\nameuser\Documents\NetBeansProjects if this is the case, just change the project folder to the html one

Comment: you are true i am working in already existing project but i delet all files of this project and make 10 new jsp files and one css file i think it is not a matter are you agree if you have any alternative please tell me thanks

Comment: Check the html document too, the links in all the href or src, if all the files are in the same folde  then there should be no problem with the design